# Какие ограничения скорости могут возникнуть при использовании websocket

Tags: сеть, websocket

Не нашел в интернетах, в документации попробовал поискать конечно, но ничего не нашел, я так понимаю, что веб-сокет внутри работает по https и держит tcp соединение открытым и следовательно скорость может быть ограничена только сетью??
Если вы владеете иной информацией или есть другая версия, пожалуйста поделитесь

Comment: Тут пишут, что других лимитов нет, но чисто на рассуждениях, без дополнительной фактологии: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17308534/8324991

Answer (score -5):

Всему своё место. Используйте протокол по назначению, а не в погоне за скоростью. WebSocket обычно быстрее HTTP, поскольку он обеспечивает двунаправленную связь в реальном времени и сокращает накладные расходы за счет устранения необходимости в новых HTTP-запросах. В свою очередь WebSocket имеет свои недостатки.

Comment: Это не ответ на заданный вопрос.

Comment: Я вам минус не ставил. Ссылки на гугль запрещены правилами, насколько я понимаю. По сравнению с собственно вопросом вы ничего нового не сказали.